# **Lazy loading CSS File - loading css only if object is in viewport**

Tags: jquery, css, function, progress-bar, lazy-loading

**Lazy loading CSS File - loading css only if object is in viewport**

I'm using a progressbar from this source : (pure css3 progressbar - http://designshack.net/articles/css/animating-personal-skill-bars-with-css3-keyframes/ ) 
It works well but I want that the animations only starts when the progressbars are in the viewport of the side.

I tried to fix it to load the specific css file async - but it doesn't work.

```
    <script>
    function loadCss(skills) {
    var l = document.createElement('link');
    l.rel = 'stylesheet';
    l.href = filename
    var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    h.parentNode.insertBefore(l, h);
    }

    function cb() {
    loadCss('.css');
    }
    var raf = requestAnimationFrame || 
    mozRequestAnimationFrame ||  
    webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
    msRequestAnimationFrame;
    if (raf) {
    raf(cb);
    } else {
    window.addEventListener('load', cb);
    }
    </script>

    <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skills.css"></noscript>
    //Fallback//
```

Maybe someone could help me. I need a function which controlls the keyframe animation (seperate css file!) or load the whole css file if the object is in viewport.

best regards

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Try to clarify your question a little bit; in particular, saying "it doesn't work" doesn't give much information. For example, if you're getting a specific error, post it. If you're getting unexpected/unwanted behavior, describe it and describe what you expected. Good luck!

Comment: @Jadhachem, thank you very much for your answer. Okay, when I use the code the css file which contains the skillbar will not be loaded - the placeholders are empty. I want if a user scroll to the section "skills" (skillbars) - only then should be loading the skillbars. Either I can controll the css animation or even better and much easier I controll the css-file itself - Lazy load the ccs when the element is in the viewport. I would prefer the second method.